# Getting time form time zone column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i have a users table with user culture. i need to get the time from time culture. For reference please find the below table.

```
           UserCulture 
------------------------------------------
(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West
(UTC-08:00) Baja California
(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi
(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore
(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore
(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore
(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore
(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore
(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore
(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore
(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore
```

i want out put "+8:00"  if it is Kuala Lumpur, Singapore

Comment: It's one columns or with comma separated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just a `varchar` column, then this can work:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(TimeZone NVARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West'),
('(UTC-08:00) Baja California'),
('(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi'),
('(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore')


SELECT TimeZone, SUBSTRING(timezone, 5, 6) AS Time FROM @t
```

Output:

```
TimeZone                                         Time
(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West         -12:00
(UTC-08:00) Baja California                      -08:00
(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi  +05:30
(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore              +08:00
```